# Django rest framework APIView same code for all methods

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Is it possible to have a method in my APIView class which runs the same piece of code independent of the method i.e. GET/POST/PUT.

Comment: Do you want to run a same piece of code for every api for GET/POST/PUT method ? or just one API's GET/POST/PUT method?

Comment: same for Get and post.. different for Put. A solution for same for all methods would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

As with Django, the `APIView` works the same way by first going through the dispatch method before deciding which request method to use so you could override that in your own view

```
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

See [dispatch methods](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/views/#dispatch-methods) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use django Middleware to meet this requirement.

```
class CommonResponseMiddleware:

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def process_request(self, request):

        path = request.path_info.lstrip('/')

        method = request.method.upper()

        if method == "DELETE":
            request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'DELETE'
            request.DELETE = QueryDict(request.body)
        if method == "PUT":
            request.META['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'PUT'
            request.PUT = QueryDict(request.body)

        params = {}
        if method == "GET":
            params = request.GET.items()
            # do what ever you want for GET method
        if method == "POST":
            params = request.POST.items()
            # do what ever you want for POST method
        if method == "PUT":
            params = request.PUT.items()
            # do what ever you want for PUT method
        if method == "DELETE":
            params = request.DELETE.items()
            # do what ever you want for DELETE method
```

then apply this middleware in settings.py.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',  # <--here
    #'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'authentication.auth.middleware.LoginRequiredMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.CommonResponseMiddleware',
]
```

You could find more about middleware, hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but I don't want to use middleware. I just wanted to know if a simple and direct solution exists for this.

Comment: Using a middleware would cripple your website for this kind of use. it would be ran for every request - regardless of this simple use case

Comment: Got it... In my mind, middleware is flexible enough, you could handle all api or just one api at this place. Good luck to find the method you want : )

Comment: @Sayse, yes, it will affect performance. but we could judge the path at the first line. if the path is not target api, skip....